# AsyncTask в java android

Tags: android, java

Пример кода:

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.properties.length; i++) {

    String text = value.properties[i].type;

    if (text.equals("one")) {
        // тут что-либо делаем (не поток)
    }

    if (text.equals("two")) {
        // тут тоже что либо делаем (не поток)
    }

    if (text.equals("thread")) {
        // а вот тут уже создаем и запускаем поток
        new CreateSpinner().execute();
    }
}
```

В чем собственном вопрос: мне нужно, чтобы цикл не продолжался до тех пор, пока не завершится поток в третьем условии.

Comment: Мне кажется, вам надо завести цикл внутри AsyncTask, а не создавать кучу потоков, и вся ваша проблема решится. По крайней мере для задачи, которую вы описали в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

То что вы поменяли немного вопрос, комментария моего не отменяет, сделайте все полностью в AsyncTask, если уж не подходит, так как я чего то не понял, то вот что мне пришло в голову:

Попробуйте реализовать через очередь, вместо массива value.properties, и рекурсию.
Эта очередь передается в метод doSomeThing(...).  
Соответственно, текущий элемент, который достается из очереди, это будет value.properties[i], и после использования удаляется и вызывается снова метод doSomeThing(...).

И в последней ветке, запускается AsyncTask, и после его выполнения вызывается doSomeThing(...) в onPostExecute(...).

Как то так

```
   public void doSMT(Queue<String> q)
   {
       String text = q.peek();
       if (text.equals("one")) {
           // тут что-либо делаем (не поток)
           //.......
           //.......
           doSMT(q);
       }
       if (text.equals("two")) {
           // тут тоже что либо делаем (не поток)
           //.......
           //.......
           doSMT(q);
       }
       if (text.equals("thread")) {
           // а вот тут уже создаем и запускаем поток
           new CreateSpinner(q).execute();
       }
   }

class CreateSpinner extens AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    private Queue<String> q
    public CreateSpinner(Queue<String> q)
    {
        this.q = q;
    }

    @Override
    public Void doinbackgroudn(Void... p)
    {
        // тут тоже что либо делаем 
                    //.......
                    //.......

    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute()
    {
        // тут тоже что либо делаем 
                    //.......
                    //.......
        doSMT(q);
    }
}
```

Решение не тянет на элегантность, но должно работать так, как вам надо.

Answer (score 0):

А в чем собственно вопрос ? описываем свой AsyncTask  в doInBackground отправляем запрос на сервер, не забываем ловить исключения - вроде бы все

Answer (score 0):

потоки в андроиде выполняются последовательно, а не параллельно (для этого апи 11+ есть метод `myTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);` ), но если тебе надо контролируемую последовательность - отправляй запросы по таймауту или после получения ответа с сервера.

Comment: немного не так сформулировал вопрос. обновил пост.

Answer (score 0):

Если дуло только в том, что бы записать результаты выполнения запроса в нужной последовательности, то почему бы просто не присвоить каждому экземпляру асинктаска индекс, и не записывать в onPostExecute() результат в массив под этим индексом?